# Is there a way to find the length of a variable in Java?

Tags: java

```
long AccountNumber = 1234567890;
public void setAccNum(long Number)
    try(the size of the account number is lesser than equal to 10){
        this.Accountnumber = Number;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: Invalid account number");
    }
```

In the above code, to validate the length of the account number, is there any function to find the length of the value in AccountNumber variable in Java?

Comment: `log base 10`!?

Comment: And by the way, most likely you shouldn't be using int/long to store the account number. What if the account number has a trailing zero, etc.? As stupid as it sounds, the most natural type to store account _numbers_ and similar identifiers is String.

Comment: The length is 64 bits.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do this, [some are](http://javadevnotes.com/java-long-to-string-examples)

**1.** `String.valueOf(AccountNumber).length()`

**2.** `(Long.toString(AccountNumber)).length()`

Answer (score 0):

To get the length convert to a string first:

```
int len = String.valueOf(this.AccountNumber).length();
```

Answer (score -1):

length is a method of String, so you can for example do

```
if (stringVar.length != 10)
{
        ...
}
```

But I'd recommend the usage of [Apache Commons Lang3 StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html), because it's methods are always null-aware.

For example

```
if (StringUtils.length(stringVar) != 10)
{
    ...
}
```

**edit**: sorry, it's a number, so like others mentioned it must be converted to String first.